# If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of G then $H \times K$ is a subgroup of $G \times G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$ then $HK= \{ hk \mid h \in H , k \in K\}$ is not necessarily a subgroup of $G$, this requires that $HK = KH$. But it follows that if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$ then $H \times K$ is a subgroup of $G \times G$.  I appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 3):

Just verify the usual conditions:

1) $e_{G\times G}=(e_G,e_G)\in H\times K$ (i.e. $H\times K$ is a non-empty set)

2) If $(x,y), (z,t)\in H\times K$ then $(x,y)(z,t)^{-1}=(xz^{-1},yt^{-1})\in H\times K$

both of which are immediately verified because $H,K$ are groups.

Answer (score 2):

use same method; set $\bar H=H\times e$ and $\bar K=e\times K$ since $\bar H\bar K=\bar K \bar H$ then $\bar H\bar K=H \times K$ is a group.

Answer (score 0):

Use the subgroup test. The set $H\times K$ contains $(e,e)$ since $e\in H$ and $e\in K$. If $(x,y),(a,b)\in H\times K$, can you conclude their product is in $H\times K$. Can you show closure under inverses?